# Unable to test component props when it's an array using vue-test utils@1 (Vue 2) and jest

Tags: vuejs2, vue-test-utils, babel-jest

I have a simple Vue 2 component that is receiving an array of objects as a prop.
I have Vue test utils version 1 for vue 2 installed as well as jest.

In my test I have this:

```
 import {shallowMount} from '@vue/test-utils';
 import UsersList from '../components/UsersList.vue;

 let wrapper;

 beforeEach(() => {
     wrapper = shallowMount(UsersList);
 });

test('it has the expected prop values', () => {
        wrapper.propsData = {
            users: [{
                id: 1,
                name: 'John Doe',
                city: 'Dallas'
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'John Smith',
                city: 'Orlando'
            }
          ]
        }

        console.log(wrapper.props()) //Returns as  { users: undefined }
        expect(wrapper.props().users).toBe('array'); //Users is undefined
    })
```

In my vue component I am receiving the users as props. I do see my users correctly in the vue dev tools...this I know the data is coming through.

```
  props: {
    users: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  },
```

Why is my users prop undefined in my test? Sorry I am somewhat new to vue test utils.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question and your question is for vue2, but in vue3 it works:

```
 const wrapper = mount(Component, {
        props: {
          matches: [
            {
              'objet': 'objet-test',
            },
            {
              'objet': 'objet-test2',
            }
          ],
       }
      })
    
   test('test with 2 matches', () => {
    expect(wrapper.html({ raw: true })).toContain('<td>objet-test')
    expect(wrapper.html({ raw: true })).toContain('<td>objet-test2')
   })
```

And the component:

```
<template>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-sm" data-test="matches">
        <thead class="table-light">
            <tr>
                <th>Objet</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="item in matches"  data-test="matches-list">
                <td>{{ item.objet }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: "Matches",
    props: {
        matches: null
    }
}
</script>
```